# Appium Safari test hangs and didn't finish

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, safari, appium, appium-ios

I'm running an Appium simple test using Safari on iOS simulator on Mac with the latest version of Xcode and Appium

but sometimes the test hangs with the message "Let's browse", nothing happens on the simulator or appium GUI....

Screenshot
[image]

Here is my tests code

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        //Emulator
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 6");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9.2");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Safari");    

        //driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

@Test
    public void WebPageFormTest() throws Exception {
        driver.get("http://saucelabs.com/test/guinea-pig");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement idElement = driver.findElement(By.id("i_am_an_id"));
        assertNotNull(idElement);
        assertEquals("I am a div", idElement.getText());
        WebElement commentElement = driver.findElement(By.id("comments"));
        assertNotNull(commentElement);
        commentElement.sendKeys("This is an awesome comment");
        WebElement submitElement = driver.findElement(By.id("submit"));
        assertNotNull(submitElement);
        submitElement.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement yourCommentsElement = driver.findElement(By.id("your_comments"));
        assertNotNull(yourCommentsElement);
        assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("your_comments")).getText().contains("This is an awesome comment"));
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }
```

Here is the log info

```
ionIdentifierKey":"6731e33c-c389-4d09-994c-f78fb7e22110"},"__selector":"_rpc_reportIdentifier:"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRSimulatorBuildKey":"13C75","WIRSimulatorProductVersionKey":"9.2","WIRSimulatorNameKey":"iPhone"},"__selector":"_rpc_reportSetup:"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sim name: iPhone
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sim build: 13C75
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRApplicationDictionaryKey":{"PID:30210":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30210","WIRIsApplicationProxyKey":false,"WIRApplicationNameKey":"Safari","WIRApplicationBundleIdentifierKey":"com.apple.mobilesafari","WIRIsApplicationActiveKey":1}}},"__selector":"_rpc_reportConnectedApplicationList:"}
info: [debug] Using remote debugger app key: PID:30210
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Selecting app PID:30210 (try #1 of 8)
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardGetListing: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRConnectionIdentifierKey":"6731e33c-c389-4d09-994c-f78fb7e22110","WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30210"},"__selector":"_rpc_forwardGetListing:"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30223","WIRIsApplicationProxyKey":true,"WIRApplicationNameKey":"","WIRApplicationBundleIdentifierKey":"com.apple.WebKit.WebContent","WIRIsApplicationActiveKey":1,"WIRHostApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30210"},"__selector":"_rpc_applicationConnected:"}
info: [REMOTE] We were notified we connected to possibly the wrong app. Using the id key suggested and trying again
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Selecting app PID:30223 (try #2 of 8)
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardGetListing: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRConnectionIdentifierKey":"6731e33c-c389-4d09-994c-f78fb7e22110","WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30223"},"__selector":"_rpc_forwardGetListing:"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30230","WIRIsApplicationProxyKey":true,"WIRApplicationNameKey":"","WIRApplicationBundleIdentifierKey":"com.apple.WebKit.WebContent","WIRIsApplicationActiveKey":1,"WIRHostApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30210"},"__selector":"_rpc_applicationConnected:"}
info: [REMOTE] We were notified we connected to possibly the wrong app. Using the id key suggested and trying again
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Selecting app PID:30230 (try #3 of 8)
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardGetListing: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRConnectionIdentifierKey":"6731e33c-c389-4d09-994c-f78fb7e22110","WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30230"},"__selector":"_rpc_forwardGetListing:"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30210","WIRListingKey":{}},"__selector":"_rpc_applicationSentListing:"}
info: [REMOTE] Empty page dictionary received. Trying again.
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Se
lecting app PID:30230 (try #4 of 8)
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardGetListing: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRConnectionIdentifierKey":"6731e33c-c389-4d09-994c-f78fb7e22110","WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30230"},"__selector":"_rpc_forwardGetListing:"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30223","WIRListingKey":{"1":{"WIRTitleKey":"Appium/welcome","WIRTypeKey":"WIRTypeWeb","WIRURLKey":"http://127.0.0.1:4723/welcome","WIRPageIdentifierKey":1}}},"__selector":"_rpc_applicationSentListing:"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Connected to app PID:30223 [[{"id":1,"title":"Appium/welcome","url":"http://127.0.0.1:4723/welcome","isKey":false}]]
info: [debug] Picking webview WEBVIEW_1
info: [debug] Attempting to set context to 'WEBVIEW_1'
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Selecting page 1 and forwarding socket setup
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketSetup: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30230","WIRConnectionIdentifierKey":"6731e33c-c389-4d09-994c-f78fb7e22110","WIRSenderKey":"6818a56b-8c02-4491-b1d9-872c88a69678","WIRPageIdentifierKey":1},"__selector":"_rpc_forwardSocketSetup:"}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30230","WIRListingKey":{"1":{"WIRTitleKey":"Google","WIRTypeKey":"WIRTypeWeb","WIRURLKey":"https://www.google.com/?client=safari&channel=iphone_bm","WIRPageIdentifierKey":1}}},"__selector":"_rpc_applicationSentListing:"}
info: [debug] Remote debugger notified us of a new page listing
info: [debug] We don't appear to have window set yet, ignoring
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Set sender key
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketData: message to remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30230","WIRListingKey":{"1":{"WIRTitleKey":"Google","WIRTypeKey":"WIRTypeWeb","WIRURLKey":"https://www.google.com/?client=safari&channel=iphone_bm","WIRPageIdentifierKey":1}}},"__selector":"_rpc_applicationSentListing:"}
info: [debug] Remote debugger notified us of a new page listing
info: [debug] We don't appear to have window set yet, ignoring
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] got applicationSentData response
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Enabled activity on page
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Unregistering from page readiness notifications
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Page loading
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Waiting for dom...
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Page loaded, verifying whether ready through readyState
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Receiving data from remote debugger
info: [debug] [REMOTE] {"__argument":{"WIRApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30230","WIRIsApplicationProxyKey":true,"WIRApplicationNameKey":"","WIRApplicationBundleIdentifierKey":"com.apple.WebKit.WebContent","WIRIsApplicationActiveKey":1,"WIRHostApplicationIdentifierKey":"PID:30210"},"__selector":"_rpc_applicationDisconnected:"}

info: [debug] [REMOTE] Checking document readyState
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending javascript command
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Sending _rpc_forwardSocketData: message to remote debugger

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"3a82a9f1-703f-4112-aa57-b39da2e69293"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 6.989 ms - 179 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"3a82a9f1-703f-4112-aa57-b39da2e69293"}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run web app on ios simulator ?

Comment: Hi @BharathVankireddy, I was trying to run the Safari Browser on the ios simulator, sometimes it works, and sometimes it stay with the message "Let's Browse"

Comment: I've had this before, but I can't exactly remember what caused it. I think it's because launching Safari is slow, and it is trying to execute driver.get before Safari loads. Try waiting/sleep for a few seconds after you initialize the driver.